# Fabric.js editing text via inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

i am working on online print media application like 'vistaprint.in' where user can modify premade designs on fabric js canvas. in fabric.js object there is no unique identifier for objects...all the text objects create a input for each them so that user can directly change desired text by just changing in input...you can see in screenshot in right side of canvas there are input for each text object...what i am doing now is when input changes i loop through all text objects and match input text and text object text if it matches then i update new text to that object..this works fine for first time but not after that...i tried but unable to find what to do to solve this.

**This is how canvas and input looks like now**
[Screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9w2A.jpg)

**and this is the function which i created now for changing text of canvas**

```
$(document).on('input', '#cardalltexthex input', function(){    
 v = $(this).attr('text');
 newtext = $(this).val();
 objs = canvas.getObjects();
 objs.forEach(function(e) {
   if (e && e.type === 'i-text') { 
   console.log(e.text);
   console.log(newtext);
     if (e.text == v) {
     e.setText(newtext);
     canvas.renderAll(); 
     }
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `id` property to `fabric` object and check that property with your `input` as below sample

No need to do `if (e.text == v)` just set all `fabric` object with some unique `id` and compare that with your input.

```js
var text;
var canvas;
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
text1 = new fabric.Text("Text", {
  id: "cardalltexthex1",
  fontSize: 70,
  selectable: false,
  left: 100,
  top: 0,
  text: "text1",
  fill: '#f00'
});
canvas.add(text1);
text2 = new fabric.Text("Text", {
  id: "cardalltexthex2",
  fontSize: 70,
  selectable: false,
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  text: "text2",
  fill: '#f00'
});
canvas.add(text2);



$('.input').on('keyup', function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  val = $(this).attr('data-text');
  newtext = $(this).val();
  input = $(this);

  objs = canvas.getObjects();
  objs.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj && obj.text == val) {
      obj.setText(newtext);
      input.attr("data-text", newtext);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width=500 height=250></canvas>

<input class="input" data-text="text1" value="text1" id="cardalltexthex1" />

<input class="input" data-text="text2" value="text2" id="cardalltexthex2" />
```

Comment: thanks for replying i know that it will work with ID but the problem is that we already created thousand of designs and not used any ids...i need to do this without IDS

Comment: no error but canvas  text changes only first time time when i edit in input

Comment: @sunilkumar edited code, You need to use `keyup` event of textbox and set old value in  `data` attribute to compare

Comment: Property setText of fabric.Text doesn't exists

Comment: @juxhinbleta `setText` is for older version. Please use `obj.set('text', text);` for new version

Comment: @yogendarji Yes, I figured that out. I'll revert my downvote. Thank you for the feedback.